# A strange situation regarding searching for '[' in varchar columns in sql server 2000

Tags: sql, escaping, sql-server-2000, sql-like

I have a table in Sql Server 2000 called `Table1`with a few columns, one of the columns is `varchar(255)`, called 'Col5'.

The contents if one of the rows in this column is `[test]`.

When I try to test for a part of this string using the `LIKE` operator, I cannot search for the `[` in any way.

This is what I get:

1- trying `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Col1 LIKE '%[%'` returns **NO** results.

2- trying `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Col1 LIKE '%[t%'` returns **NO** results.

3- trying `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Col1 LIKE '%t]%'` returns 1 results which as expected.

4- trying `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Col1 LIKE '%test%'` returns 1 results which as expected.

This is a strange behaviour, is it a bug, what's going on, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That character has special meaning in [the pattern syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) and needs to be escaped either by defining an explicit escape character

```
where Col1 like '%/[%' ESCAPE '/'
```

or by using more square brackets

```
where Col1 like  '%[[]%'
```

In addition to its role in escaping characters it is used in the syntax when defining ranges or sets of characters to match. e.g. `LIKE '[0-9]%'` to find all values starting with a digit.

When the range or set is not closed off with a `]` it appears as though SQL Server just adds one on to the end. So `c like '%[%'` is treated as `c like '%[%]'` and finds all values containing the `%` character.